# "A is claimed to follow from B" vs "B is offered as support for A"

Tags: comparison

These two following sentences are from an LSAT. "It" in both sentences refers to the same sentence in the stimulus. Each sentence below is presented as answer choices and thus I am trying to compare them:

1. It is a conclusion that is claimed to follow from the premise that A is B.
2. It is a conclusion for which the premise that A is B is offered as support.

What's the difference in terms of their implication and tone? I felt that 1. implies the conclusion follows from the premise regardless of other information in the stimulus. On the other hand, 2. implies the premises is one of the support for the conclusion, probably in concert with other information. But I am really not sure.

Any help and comments would be helpful!

Thank you for your time,
Leon